# Cygwin gfortran read before write command

Tags: cygwin, fortran, gfortran

I'm executing a f90 script in Cygwin using `gfortran` and when i execute (run) the output with `./a` it leaves a blank space asking for input without printing out the prompt (write) command.

```
  program circle
  real r, area
  write (*,*) 'Give radius r:'
  read  (*,*) r
  area = 3.14159*r*r
  write (*,*) 'Area = ', area

  stop
  end
```

---

```
$ gfortran circle.f    
$ ./a  
    1  
      Give radius r:  
     Area =    3.1415901
```

It's suppose to be

```
$ ./a
 Give radius r:
1
 Area =    3.1415901
```

What is happening here? Please help.

Comment: You'll need to provide your Fortran code in order for us to help.

Comment: My immediate assumption is you have `read` before `write` or `print`. If you want any more help, you'll have to actually do some work and post your code.

Comment: Actual code is included above. Thank you so much.

Comment: code works fine for me, using gfortran4.8.2 on cygwin

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports Fortran 2003 you could use the [`flush`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-lin/GUID-188AE6E5-7E3A-41EA-AE71-F0726FC5024C.htm) statement:

```
program circle
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: stdin=>input_unit, &
                                           stdout=>output_unit, &
                                           stderr=>error_unit
  implicit none
  real :: r, area

  write (stdout,*) 'Give radius r:'
  flush(stdout)
  read  (stdin,*) r
  area = 3.14159*r*r
  write (stdout,*) 'Area = ', area

end program
```